# Remove a list of stopwords from a Counter in python

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, nltk

I've got a function in NLTK to generate a concordance list, which would look like

```
concordanceList = ["this is a concordance string something", 
               "this is another concordance string blah"]
```

and I have another function which returns a Counter dictionary with the counts of each word in the concordanceList

```
def mostCommonWords(concordanceList):
  finalCount = Counter()
  for line in concordanceList:
    words = line.split(" ")
    currentCount = Counter(words)
    finalCount.update(currentCount)
  return finalCount
```

The problem I have is how best to remove stopwords from the resulting Counter, so that, when I call

```
mostCommonWords(concordanceList).most_common(10)
```

the result isn't just {"the": 100, "is": 78, "that": 57}.

I think that pre-processing the text to remove stopwords is out, because I still need the concordance strings to be instances of grammatical language. Basically, I'm asking if there's a simpler way to do this than creating a stopwords Counter for stopwords, setting the values low, and then making yet another Counter like so:

```
stopWordCounter = Counter(the=1, that=1, so=1, and=1)
processedWordCounter = mostCommonWords(concordanceList) & stopWordCounter
```

which should set the count values for all stopwords to 1, but it seems hacky.

Edit: Additionally, I'm having trouble actually making such a stopWordCounter, because if I want to include reserved words like "and", I get an invalid syntax error. Counters have easy to use union and intersection methods, which would make the task fairly simple; are there equivalent methods for dictionaries?

Comment: RE: Your edit regarding the invalid syntax error. `and` is reserved but `"and"` is a string.  You should be using `Counter(["and"])` to create a counter with the string `"and"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the stop words during tokenization...

```
stop_words = frozenset(['the', 'a', 'is'])
def mostCommonWords(concordanceList):
    finalCount = Counter()
    for line in concordanceList:
        words = [w for w in line.split(" ") if w not in stop_words]
        finalCount.update(words)  # update final count using the words list
    return finalCount
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to create all those new `Counter`s inside your function; you can do:

```
for line in concordanceList:
    finalCount.update(line.split(" "))
```

instead.

Second, a `Counter` is a kind of dictionary, so you can delete items directly:

```
for sword in stopwords:
    del yourCounter[sword]
```

It doesn't matter whether `sword` is in the `Counter` - this won't raise an exception regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

One, don't count the stopwords when updating your `Counter` - which you can do more concisely, since `Counter` objects can accept an iterable as well as another mapping for `update`:

```
def mostCommonWords(concordanceList):
    finalCount = Counter()
    stopwords = frozenset(['the', 'that', 'so'])
    for line in concordanceList:
        words = line.strip().split(' ')
        finalCount.update([word for word in words if word not in stopwords])
    return finalCount
```

Alternatively, you can use `del` to actually remove them from the `Counter` once you're done.

I've also added a `strip` call on `line` prior to `split`. If you were to use `split()` and the default behavior of splitting on all whitespace, you wouldn't need that, but `split(' ')` will not consider newline to be something to split on, so the last word of each line would have a trailing `\n` and would be considered distinct from any other appearances. `strip` gets rid of that.

Comment: Awesome, coming from Javascript, so I had no idea that an empty split() could be so useful...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for flattening the items into words, ignoring any stop words and providing that as input to a single `Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

lines = [
    "this is a concordance string something", 
    "this is another concordance string blah"
]

stops = {'this', 'that', 'a', 'is'}    
words = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in lines)
count = Counter(word for word in words if word not in stops)
```

Or, that last bit can be done as:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
count = Counter(ifilterfalse(stops.__contains__, words))
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i think @JonClements' answer was the most elegant. BTW, there is already a list of `stopwords` in NLTK, just in case the OP didn't know, see [NLTK stopword removal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735733/nltk-stopword-removal-issue)

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

lines = [
    "this is a concordance string something", 
    "this is another concordance string blah"
]

stops = stopwords.words('english')
words = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in lines)
count = Counter(word for word in words if word not in stops)
count = Counter(ifilterfalse(stops.__contains__, words))
```

Also, the `FreqDist` module in NLTK has more NLP related features as compared to `collections.Counter`. http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.FreqDist-class.html

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if 'the' in counter:
    del counter['the']
```

Comment: This works, but the stopwords list is going to be 100 or so words long, so I can't type out conditionals for each word I want to remove/ignore. Thank you though.